# Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps, guarded by an unrelated 'mounted' check

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is the error saying "`Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps, guarded by an unrelated 'mounted' check.`"? Is the mounted getter deprecated?

```
if (context.mounted) {
  pop(context);
}
```

Comment: Is this inside Stateful/StatelessWidget? In StatefulWidget you can use `if (mounted)`

Comment: The issue was because i was using context.mounted instead of mounted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now in newer version of flutter you can use `mounted` directly inside `StatefulWidget`

instead of using

```dart
if (context.mounted) {
  pop(context);
}
```

Use

```dart
if (mounted) {
  pop(context);
}
```

you can check the details when to use `context.mounted` and `mounted` here: [use_build_context_synchronously](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/use_build_context_synchronously)

Comment: in Stateless widget the context.mounted is working fine and not giving any warnings.

Comment: read the doc at the given link. it is given that use only `mounted` in Sate and use `context.mounted` in SatelessWidget

Answer (score 5):

whenever you need to pass context, try to bind it inside this condition,

```
if(mounted)
{
  //your code where context need to be passed
}
```