don't use BuildContext across sync gaps, even if I check for context.mounted
I am using flutter 3.22.3 and Dart 3.4.4 and my editor still warns me about context ... even if I check if the context is mounted.
I have this helper function showToastMessage and the async gaps:
void showToastMessage(BuildContext context, String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text(message))
    );
}

// somewere in the code an async func

void _submit async {
    ...
    var result = await CallAPi().postData(data, '/login');
    
    ...
    
    // check the context !!!
    if (context.mounted) {
        showToastMessage(context, result.message); // it still complains about the context "Don`t use BuildContext across async gaps ...."
    }
}

I am checking like in the documentation for the context.... so why I am still get the warning ????
What am I missing ?

same question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/78018523/14466860

Now in newer version of flutter you can use mounted directly inside StatefulWidget
instead of using
if (context.mounted) {
  pop(context);
}

Use
if (mounted) {
  pop(context);
}

you can check the details when to use context.mounted and mounted here: use_build_context_synchronously

indeed the warning goes away.....I am migrating from an older version of flutter :) Thx
